# Where did Hayek say knowledge is the ability to learn?

Tags: reference-request, history-economic-thought

If I'm not mistaken, in some work Hayek mentions that knowledge as he means it consists not so much in the awareness of facts as in the ability to learn.

It may have been in a passage concerning entrepreneurship.

Does anyone know whether that's the case and where?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Individualism and Economic Order, p 155, "most of [knowledge] consists in a technique of thought..."